# DirectoryEntry CommitChanges() not Committing Changes?

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

Before you outright close out this question as a duplicate, it's worth noting that the answer did not work.

So here's what I've tried thus far:

First attempt was to use .InvokeSet on the record:

```
adUser.InvokeSet("department", department);
adUser.CommitChanges();
```

Second attempt was to follow the answer on [Calling commitChanges() does nothing in Active Directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141372/calling-commitchanges-does-nothing-in-active-directory) and try accessing the native object directly:

```
IADsTSUserEx nativeUser = (IADsTSUserEx)adUser.NativeObject;
nativeUser.Department = department;
adUser.CommitChanges();
```

Following up that with `IADsUser` instead.

Finally, I just tried setting it from the Value property:

```
adUser.Properties["department"].Value = department;
adUser.CommitChanges();
```

So I'm at a loss here. None of the above actually worked at saving changes. I have write access, and I'm not getting any exceptions. Am I just missing something, here? I'd like to think it's not a case of me trying to argue [Select is Broken](http://www.travisswicegood.com/2009/01/04/select-isn-t-broken/)...

**EDIT: See answer below.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the problem was a case of my impatience.

```
adUser.Properties["department"].Value = department;
adUser.CommitChanges();
```

did exactly what I needed; changes just hadn't replicated through all the AD servers at that point.

Comment: Welcome to the world of replication :)

Comment: Will you show the code for finding the adUser?  Did you use $searcher.findOne()